# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular boiler plate like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>local</title>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="csrf-token" value="Mjhs4vz2ysVuHOH2WPbyYRMGQDRIR0QHJeRv7CSs">


    <!-- CDN -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      "use strict";


      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui'], function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {

        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

        //Setting headers
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');


      });

      myApp.directive('myEnter', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
              });

              event.preventDefault();
            }
          });
        };
      });


      myApp.controller('youtubeController', function youtubeController($scope, $log, $http) {

        $scope.download = function() {
          $scope.data = {
            link: $scope.link,
          };

          $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/youtube/download',
            data: angular.toJson($scope.data)
          })


          .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("%cSuccess!", "color: green;");
            console.log(response);
            $scope.refresh();
            $scope.showModal = false;
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("%cError", "color: red;");
            console.log(response);
          });

        };

      });

    </script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="youtubeController">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center" style="width: 100%;">
        <input type="text" name="link" ng-mdel="link">
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="download()">Download</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

For some reasons, I kept getting this error in my console, and I don't know what is the cause of that.

[image]

---

My JSFiddle for that : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/L3oguqk4/

---

Any hints on what I should look into ?

Comment: there are *hundreds* of questions here that all are basically the same answer, this is like asking "how do I solve a memory leak".  Start off with using angular.js instead of angular.min.js to get a useful error.

Comment: That clearly reveals `Module 'ui' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.`.  There doesn't seem to be a `ui` module in the fiddle.

Comment: Where and how do u see that error in console ? I tried to look for those and I don't see that.

Comment: **exactly as I said in the first comment**.  When troubleshooting JavaScript, use the **full** library instead of the **minified** library;  in this case, `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find more information about what the error means by following the URL in the error message.

The error is complaining about a module `ui`. What is `ui`? Are you sure you are including the source JS file for this module?

By removing the reference to this module, it looks like you have another error:

`$ is not defined`

So, you don't have jQuery included, but you are trying to access jQuery methods.

https://jsfiddle.net/L3oguqk4/1/

Just follow this pattern until you have eliminated all the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to fix your code as much as possible, remove name 'youtubeController', added jquery and also created a config section. You should be better of creating a httpintercepter and use $httpProvider.interceptors.push to modify your header.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>local</title>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="csrf-token" value="Mjhs4vz2ysVuHOH2WPbyYRMGQDRIR0QHJeRv7CSs">


    <!-- CDN -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      "use strict";


      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
      
      myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider,$httpProvider) {

        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

        //Setting headers
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');


      });

      myApp.directive('myEnter', function() {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.$eval(attrs.myEnter);
              });

              event.preventDefault();
            }
          });
        };
      });


      myApp.controller('youtubeController', function ($scope, $log, $http) {

        $scope.download = function() {
          $scope.data = {
            link: $scope.link,
          };

          $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/youtube/download',
            data: angular.toJson($scope.data)
          })


          .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("%cSuccess!", "color: green;");
            console.log(response);
            $scope.refresh();
            $scope.showModal = false;
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("%cError", "color: red;");
            console.log(response);
          });

        };

      });

    </script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="youtubeController">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center" style="width: 100%;">
        <input type="text" name="link" ng-mdel="link">
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="download()">Download</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change this line:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui'], function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
```

to:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
```

You didn't need **ui** module.